# What does include means in gosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

To use gosu in ruby program, we have to called out gosu.

```
require "gosu"
```

But what does include means in a gosu program.

```
require "gosu"
include Gosu
```

what is the purpose of `include Gosu` in the program and what does it do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including a module in a given context  makes the methods defined in that module available in that context.

In this case, you're making the methods defined the `Gosu` module available in the current context.

See [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-include).

For example, including `Test` causes `foo` to be added to the current context, so that `foo` can be invoked:

```
module Test
  def foo
    "bar"
  end
end

include Test

foo # "bar"
```